# Combine 2 regex with a priority?

Tags: php, regex

I use the following regex to match all the **1bhp** or **12bhp** or **123bhp** or **1234bhp**.
I do not know if it is the best way of writing it, but it works.

```
preg_match_all('/(\d{1}|\d{2}|\d{3}|\d{4})bhp/', $str2b, $bhps);
```

However if it does not match anything, I would like to match the content of the

`<td class="something">THIS</td>`

I know that the regex for this will be `!<td class="something">(.*?)</td>!is`

My problem is that I have difficulties on have a priority in the first regex and if nothing is found for the `bhp` then to match the content of the `<td>` that will always be there.

Thank you

**EDIT IMPORTANT**

You can find a piece of the HTML here http://codepad.org/AZ4g6HDZ
The second tr block does not have the bhp, so it gets the next. So having this in mind, I am ok if no bhp found to get the `<td class="mileage">this</td>` that is after the bhp on the same `<tr>`

Comment: Just use 2 `preg_match`es. There is nothing wrong in using 2 x `preg_match` + `if` PS: `\d{1,4}bhp`

Comment: @zerkms Can you give me an example? I think the solution provided in the answers is not correct. However I tried the 2 preg match without luck because the second always rewrites the first

Comment: show your attempt first

Comment: @zerkms i have edited the question with my attempts.
In my HTML there are a lot of <tr></tr> that contain this info. If one <tr></tr> does not have all the info, then there is a messed up because the next goes to the place of the previous. So I am trying to fill it every time.

Comment: `So I am trying to fill it every time.` - This means you have to match both at the same time using a common start/end tag. As important as you say this is, you fail to notice at least 2 answers below that show you how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
'/\d{1,4}bhp/'
```

Will do exactly the same as your first regex. If then you want to match the div if that regex does not match, wrap it in parenthesis and use `|` to add them together. This creates:

```
'/(\d{1,4}bhp|<td class="something">(.*?)<\/td>)/'
```

Edit: Check here if this is the result you wanted:
http://regex101.com/r/pV1gB5 (all lines match)

Comment: This will match both strings no matter what. The OP wants the second to be tested only if the first didn't match.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
<?php

$str2b = '<td class="something">THIS</td>';
// or maybe this: $str2b = '1234bhp';

preg_match_all('/(\d{1}|\d{2}|\d{3}|\d{4})bhp/', $str2b, $bhps);

if( empty($bhps[0]) ) {
    preg_match_all('!<td class="something">(.*?)</td>!is', $str2b, $bhps);
}


var_dump($bhps);

?>
```

So, `preg_match_all` puts full pattern matches into `$bhps[0]`. If there was no match, it is empty. We then check for your second regex if it is.

As mentioned in the other answer, you can also fix your first regex to be more efficient by using `/(\d{1,4})bhp/`.

Also, you should consider whether you need [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) or just regular [`preg_match`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my code I use a for i loop because there are about 15 tr blocks containing this data. If one tr block does not have all the bhp data, then there is a messed up because the next goes to the place of the previous. So I am trying to fill it every time.

I tested it and I believe that bhps[0] will never be empty...

Comment: @Shilloftanos Can you provide an example of what `$str2b` looks like? This would help in coming up with an answer.

Comment: Yes I have uploaded it here http://codepad.org/AZ4g6HDZ

Actually is more, there are 15. The middle one does not have any bhp. So it gets the bhp from the next.

Comment: So having this in mind, I am ok if no bhp found to get the `<td class="mileage">this</td>` that is after the bhp

Comment: @Shilloftanos Yes, the code in my answer will do this for you. just replace `"something"` with `"mileage"` and you will have what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, this is an example with your html code and the class *details*:

```
<?php
$subject = <<<'LOD'
<tr class="main_row pc">
    <td class="details">
        <div class="attribs">
            Αγροτικό/Pickup
            2500cc,
            102bhp,
            Manual,
            Πετρέλαιο,
            Ασπρο,
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="registration">9 / 95</td>
    <td class="mileage">151.000</td>
    <td class="price">
    <span class="p_p">€ 6.300</span>
    </td>
</tr>


<tr class="main_row pc">

    <td class="details">
        <div class="attribs">
            Λιμουζίνα/Sedan
            1800cc,
            Manual,
            Βενζίνη,
            Γαλάζιο,
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="registration">3 / 00</td>
    <td class="mileage">0</td>
    <td class="price">
    <span class="p_p">€ 900</span>
    </td>
</tr>



<tr class="main_row pc">
    <td class="details">    
        <div class="attribs">
            Αγροτικό/Pickup
            2400cc,
            1bhp,
            Manual,
            Πετρέλαιο,
            Κόκκινο,
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="registration">1 / 95</td>
    <td class="mileage">1</td>
    <td class="price">
    <span class="p_p">€ 2.650</span>
    </td>
</tr>
LOD;

$pattern = <<<'LOD'
~ 
<td \s* class="details">\s*  
(?>
    (?> [^0-9<]++ | [0-9](?![0-9]{0,3}bhp) | <(?!/td>) )* \K
    [0-9]{1,4}bhp
  |
    \K (?> [^<]++ | <(?!/td>) )* 
)
~ix
LOD;


preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work

```
 $string = '
       # removed to reduce noise
 ';

 preg_match_all (
  '~<td\ class="details">(?|(?:(?!</?td>).)*?(\d{1,4}bhp)(?:(?!</?td>).)*?|((?:(?!</?td>).)*?))</td>~s',
  $string,
  $matches,
  PREG_PATTERN_ORDER
 );

 print_r( $matches[1] );

 ------------------------

 Result: 
 Array
 (
     [0] => 102bhp
     [1] => 
         <div class="attribs">
             ??µ?????a/Sedan
             1800cc,
             Manual,
             ?e?????,
             Ga?????,
         </div>

     [2] => 1bhp
 )
```

The regex uses a branch reset, here it is expanded and with margin annotations  -

```
      <td\ class="details">
      (?|
           (?:
                (?! </?td> )
                . 
           )*?
 br 1      ( \d{1,4} bhp )           # (1)
           (?:
                (?! </?td> )
                . 
           )*?
        |  
 br 1      (                         # (1 start)
                (?:
                     (?! </?td> )
                     . 
                )*?
    1      )                         # (1 end)
      )
      </td>
```